# Air Elemental's Whirlwind

Tags: pathfinder-1e

Ref: [Small Air Elemental](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/outsiders/elemental/elemental-air/small-air-elemental), [Whirlwind](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/rules-for-monsters/universal-monster-rules#TOC-Whirlwind-Su-)

1. What kind of action must an Air Elemental take to become a whirlwind?
2. How often can an Air Elemental use Whirlwind?

   The ability's template includes a frequency

   > whirlwind (3/day, 10–30 ft. high, 1d6+6 damage, DC 15)

   But the bestiary entry for Small Air Elemental doesn't.

   > whirlwind (DC 12, 10-20 ft.)
3. If a Small Air Elemental creates a 20' tall whirlwind, what's the size category of the whirlwind?

   > Creatures one or more size categories smaller than the whirlwind might take damage when caught in the whirlwind [...]

   Is it the size of the creature in its normal form (Small Air Elemental affects Tiny creatures), or does it go by the height of the whirlwind (≥10' affects Medium creatures, ≥20' affects Large creatures, etc)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Answers

1. The special attack [whirlwind](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/rules-for-monsters/universal-monster-rules#TOC-Whirlwind-Su-) is a supernatural ability and, as a supernatural ability with an unstated activation time, [it takes a standard action to activate](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat#Table-Actions-in-Combat).
2. According to the whirlwind ability and the description of the [Small air elemental](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/outsiders/elemental/elemental-air/small-air-elemental), a Small air elemental can remain a whirlwind for 1 round after which it resumes its original form. It can then take a standard action to once again assume whirlwind form. It can do this any number of times per day (which, given the ability's limited duration, isn't usually a big deal).
3. A Small air elemental can create a whirlwind with a height between 10 ft. and 20 ft. According to this [chart](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat/space-reach-threatened-area-templates) a whirlwind with a height of 10 ft. to 15 ft. is Large, and a whirlwind with a height of 20 ft. is Huge. The size categories of affected creatures are determined by the *whirlwind*'s size category not the size category of the creature *making* the whirlwind (i.e. "Creatures one or more size categories smaller than the whirlwind...").

Answer (score 2):

Supernatural abilities take a standard action to activate. This is referenced on the following chart, under Standard actions:

> http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat#TOC-Standard-Actions

Size, Reach, and Threatened area:

> http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat/space-reach-threatened-area-templates

A whirlwind 10-30 feet tall can be treated as a Large, or a Huge Whirlwind, depending on the elemental. The special attack text for whirlwind states the following:

> The whirlwind is always 5 feet wide at its base, but its height and width at the top vary from creature to creature (minimum 10 feet high). A whirlwind’s width at its peak is always equal to half of its height. **The creature controls the exact height, but it must be at least 10 feet high.**

Emphasis mine.

An Air elemental can use a whirlwind for up to 1 round for every 2 HD they have. If the creature has a fly speed, it can continue to fly at that same speed while in whirlwind form; otherwise it gains a fly speed equal to its base land speed (average maneuverability) while in whirlwind form.

Which is located here:

> http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/rules-for-monsters/universal-monster-rules#TOC-Whirlwind-Su-

Comment: That last part says how long it can stay as a whirlwind once it uses the ability, but the question was how often it can use the ability.